# How to install google protoc by placing binary somwhere in PATH

Tags: 16.04, bashrc

I downloaded the protoc zip file here :
https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download/v3.4.0/protoc-3.4.0-linux-x86_64.zip (its a <2MB file)

The installation instructions say that I need to place the binary somewhere in my PATH

So I edited my `~/.bashrc` file and added this :

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/tanmay/Downloads/protoc-3.4.0-linux-x86_64/bin/
```

But still protoc version is reported as 2.4 and not 3.4. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `PATH` is searched *in order* ...

Comment: i dont understand. can you please elaborate

Comment: I removed the version installed by apt-get and it worked. It picked up the path via bashrc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PATH` is searched in order, so if you want the version in your `Downloads` directory to take precedence over other versions you must place the new path first:

```
export PATH="/home/tanmay/Downloads/protoc-3.4.0-linux-x86_64/bin/:$PATH"
```